# XML comparer C#

Tags: c#, xml, algorithm

I want to compare 2 XML files.
Looks easy if both of them have an identical structure. But not in my case :( 
My files looks like:

```
<root>
 <t>
  <child1>
    <cc1>val</cc1>
    <cc2>val</cc2>
     ......
  </child1>
  <child2>
    <cc1>val</cc1>
    <cc2>val</cc2>
     ......
  </child2>
  <child2>
    <cc1>val</cc1>
    <cc2>val</cc2>
     ......
  </child2>
    .......
  <child3>
    <cc1>val</cc1>
    <cc2>val</cc2>
     ......
  </child3>
   ....
 </t>
 <t>
   ...
 </t>
 .....
</root>
```

And they could have any numbers of childes, and childes of childes...
The task is

1. To compare only one defined  block. I need search it for value of 1st child's child (child1.cc1.value in this example)
2. During the comparetion some nodes could be skipped (the names of skipped nodes stored somewhere, for example, in strings array)
3. It is possible to have multiple identical nodes like . And if child2 isn't ignored, then I need to make sure they are the same amount, and they all coincide with the corresponding second file. So there could be next situation:

1st file contains:

```
 <child2><cc1>1</cc1>...</child2>
 <child2><cc1>3</cc1>...</child2>
 <child2><cc1>2</cc1>...</child2>
```

2st file contains:

```
 <child2><cc1>2</cc1>...</child2>
 <child2><cc1>1</cc1>...</child2>
 <child2><cc1>3</cc1>...</child2>
```

And that means they are corresponds each other.
So they could be in the random order.

Now I can't make a decision how to realize this algorithm. I suggested to use DataSet objects, but this XML-structure looks too difficult for simply using DataTables, dataRows and etc..

Now I'm trying XmlNodes. But I haven't realized that part where I have several identical nodes with different data in random order.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How large are your XML files? And how complex is the structure in reality?

If not too large or complex then I would recommend parsing the whole file into a class structure and then performing your validation on the properties of the classes. For example (pseudocode)...

```
xmlClass file1 = new xmlClass(file1info);
xmlClass file2 = new xmlClass(file2info);

//Custom classes have now parsed XML files in whichever way you like

if (file1.numberOfChildren != file2.numberOfChildren) 
{
  //comparison fail
} 
elseif (!file1.orderOfChildrenSame(file2))
{
  //comparison fail
}
else
{
  //comparison success
}
```

Obviously the exact implementation of the methods and properties of your `xmlClass` will depend on your exact requirements.

XmlClass may be of the rough layout...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;

public class XmlClass
{ 
    private XmlDocument _xmlDoc;
    private List<ChildClass> _children As New List<ChildClass>();

    public XmlClass(FileInfo fil){
        _xmlDoc = New XmlDocument();
        _xmlDoc.Load(fil.FullName);

        ParseChildren();

        _xmlDoc = Nothing;
    }

    private void ParseChildren(){
        XmlNodeList ndl = _xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/root/t") //select all <t>s
        foreach (xmlNode nodT in ndl.Nodes){
            foreach (xmlNode nodChild in nodT.ChildNodes()){
                _children.Add(new ChildClass(nodChild));
            }
        }
        // Now _children contains all child nodes of <t>s and can be worked with logically
    }

    public int numberOfChildren
    {
        get {return _children.Count();}
    }
}
```

You will obviously need to implement `ChildClass` - which may in turn contain a collection of `ChildClass` itself (allowing the hierarchy you describe). You will also need to implement the other validation methods as you require. Also you may need to implement other classes to represent other node types within the document which you are interested in.

Don't parse more than you need to in order to validate! - It depends what your end goal is.

**PS**

I would also suggest that this XML format is not very "nice" in terms of the `<child1>`, `<child2>` set-up. It would be much more XMLesque to have `<child id="1">`, `<child id="2">` etc. As presumably `<child1>` and `<child2>` are essentially the same *type* of node...

Comment: >>`<child id="1">, <child id="2">`
Oh, if I could choose...
But your idea is very pretty! At least I like it and I will try.

Comment: @Ksice I wouldn't say it's very pretty! But I have used similar code to verify integrity of XML documents. Breaking it into classes can help to clarify the problem in your mind also. btw the above code is totally untested - may need some tweaks :)